# Laravel Deep relationship for product variants

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many-through, has-many

I have the following Database structure: https://dbdiagram.io/d/5c4b590def2dd100140d5997

Hopefully the diagram helps explain the setup better than words.

I have a product and I have generated the possible variants based on the product options/values. Now I am listing the variants in a table so that I can change the pricing on each combination, using the following code:

```php
@foreach($product->variants as $variant)
<tr>
    <td>{!! Form::text('variants[' . $variant->id . '][sku]', (is_null($variant->sku) ? $variant->reference : $variant->sku)) !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::number('variants[' . $variant->id . '][price]', $variant->price) !!}</td>
    <td>{{ $variant->image }}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::number('variants[' . $variant->id . '][stock]', $variant->stock) !!}</td>
    @foreach($variant->productoptions() as $productoption)
        <td>{{ $productoption->product_option_value_name }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

On the ProductVariant model I have the following method to get the specific names for the product options:

```php
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function productoptions()
{
    return $this->select('product_options.name as product_option_name', 'product_option_values.name as product_option_value_name')
        ->where('product_variants.id', '=', $this->id)
        ->join('product_variant_values', 'product_variants.id', '=', 'product_variant_values.product_variant_id')
        ->join('product_options', 'product_options.id', '=', 'product_variant_values.product_option_id')
        ->join('product_option_values', 'product_option_values.id', '=', 'product_variant_values.product_option_value_id')->get();
}
```

However, this leads to an n+1 issue (which could be hundreds of calls, if a product e.g. a T Shirt has lots of Sizes, Colours, etc) as it will do a database call for each variant, so I'm looking at trying to eager load this instead. But that means I have to look at using an Eloquent Relationship.

Here's what I've tried so far using the `staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep` package:

```php
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function productoptions()
{
    return $this->hasManyDeep(ProductOptionValue::class, [ProductVariantValue::class, ProductOption::class], ['product_variant_id', 'id', 'product_option_id'], ['id', 'product_option_id', 'id']);
}
```

The problem with this is that it gets out all of the option values, instead of the ones specific to that variant.

Hopefully all of this makes sense, if not please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Try adding `->whereColumn('product_option_values.id', '=', 'product_variant_values.product_option_value_id')` to the relationship.

Comment: I was literally just doing this now, I knew I wasn't far off achieving what I was after. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereColumn()` to add the missing constraint:

```php
public function productoptions()
{
    return $this->hasManyDeep(ProductOptionValue::class, [ProductVariantValue::class, ProductOption::class], ['product_variant_id', 'id', 'product_option_id'], ['id', 'product_option_id', 'id'])
        ->whereColumn('product_option_values.id', '=', 'product_variant_values.product_option_value_id');
}
```